# I want to create a Pre Loading Screen with JS HTML CSS JQuery (Optional) and no backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to create a `Pre Loading Screen` so it let users not to leave my page if my website loads late to. I am ready with all my animations i want to show while loading the screen and have put all of them in a div called loadup. I want the loadup div to appear at start and disappear when page loads up. I want the div to have white background while it loads instead of overlay.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery window.load method works after all conten gets loaded like image, js etc. The preload div will cover entire screen from the beginning and when all content load will finish it will be set as display:none.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/app.css">
    <title>Preloading Screen</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="pre-load">
        <p class="pre-load-text">Hello world</p>
    </div>
    <div class="page-main">
        <header>Your header</header>
        <div class="container">
            <p>Your page content</p>
        </div>
        <footer>Your footer</footer>
    </div>
    <script
        src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"
        integrity="sha256-ZosEbRLbNQzLpnKIkEdrPv7lOy9C27hHQ+Xp8a4MxAQ="
        crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>
    <script>
        $(window).load(function() {
            $('.pre-load').css('display', 'none')
        })
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```